# Interpreter in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Apology in advance as there is going to be a large block of code here. I will post the code first, followed by the question.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; UTILITY FUNCTIONS
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Converts a scheme-expression into a string
;; INPUT: a scheme-expression EXP
;; OUTPUT: a SCHEME String corresponding to EXP
(define (exp->string exp)
  (cond ((number? exp) (number->string exp))
        ((symbol? exp) (symbol->string exp))
        ((list? exp) (exp->string (car exp)))))

;; INPUT: a list of lists
;; OUTPUT: a list containing all elements of the first-level lists
(define (flatten list-of-lists)
  (cond ((null? list-of-lists) '())
        (else (append (car list-of-lists) (flatten (cdr list-of-lists))))))

;; this is for all error handling.
;; programmers don't use this function but
;; the interpreter calls this function to
;; signal some type of programmer error
(define (error msg)
  (display "ERROR: ")
  (display msg)
  (newline))

;; THERE ARE TWO SUPPORTED TYPES: 'int and 'boolean
;; INPUT: an element of the ART-C language
;; OUTPUT: the type of that element
(define (type-of val)
  (cond ((number? val) 'int)
        ((boolean? val) 'boolean)))

;; A MAP is a list of key-value pairs
;; INPUT: a MAP and a KEY
;; OUTPUT: The value associated with the key or 'error
(define (map-get map x)
  (cond ((null? map) 'error)
        ((equal? (car (car map)) x) (cadr (car map)))
        (else (map-get (cdr map) x))))

;; INPUT : A MAP AND KEY
;; OUTPUT : true if the key is in the map and false otherwise
(define (map-contains map x)
  (cond ((null? map) #f)
        ((equal? (car (car map)) x) #t)
        (else (map-contains (cdr map) x))))

;; INPUT : A MAP, KEY and VALUE
;; OUTPUT: The map that results from replacing the key with the new value.  If
;; the map doesn't contain KEY, then 'error is returned
(define (map-replace map key val)
  (cond ((null? map) 'error)
        ((equal? (car (car map)) key)
         (cons (list key val) (cdr map)))
        (else
         (cons (car map) (map-replace (cdr map) key val)))))

;; INPUT : A MAP, Key and Value
;; OUTPUT : The map that results from adding a key-value pair.  This
;; allows for duplicate keys (the most-recently added is nearer the front of the list
(define (map-add map key val)
  (cons (list key val) map))

;; INPUT: A MAP and KEY
;; OUTPUT: The map that results from deleting the key.  No errors occur if the map
;; doesn't contain the key
(define (map-delete map key)
  (cond ((null? map) map)
        ((equal? (car (car map)) key) (cdr map))
        (else (cons (car map)
                    (map-delete (cdr map) key)))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; TYPEMAP : A SEMANTIC DOMAIN DATA TYPE
;; A typemap is a list of block-level declarations.
;; FORM: ((var1 type1) (var2 type2) (var3 type3) ... )
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; INPUT: NONE
;; OUTPUT: AN empty typemap
(define (typemap-create-empty) '())

;; INPUT: A TYPEMAP
;; OUTPUT: The type of variable x
(define (typemap-type-of tm x)
  (map-get tm x))

;; INPUT: A TYPEMAP
;; OUTPUT: THE TYPEMAP THAT RESULTS FROM INSERTING A DECLARATIONS
(define (typemap-add tm decl)
  (map-add tm (car decl) (cadr decl)))

(define (typemap-delete tm key)
  (map-delete tm key))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; STATE : A SEMANTIC DOMAIN DATA TYPE
;; A LIST OF (VAR, VALUE) pairs
;; FORM :  ( (var1 val1) (var2 val2) ... )
;; NOTE: A map can contain duplicate keys but innermost KEYS occur
;;       before outermost KEYS and hide them
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; INPUT : NONE
;; OUTPUT: AN EMPTY STATE
(define (state-create-empty) '())

;; INPUT: STATE and ID
;; OUTPUT: a new state such that the innermost scope now contains a
;;         new binding for the specified ID.  The bindings value is 'undefined.
(define (state-add state id)
  (map-add state id 'undefined))

;; INPUT : STATE and ID
;; OUTPUT: A new state such that the innermost id is removed
(define (state-delete state id)
  (map-delete state id))

;; INPUT: STATE and ID
;; OUTPUT: The value associated with the specified ID in the given state
(define (state-get-value state id)
  (map-get state id))

;; INPUT: STATE and ID
;; OUTPUT: A new state that results from changing the mapping from id->value in
;;         the specified state
(define (state-update state id value)
  (map-replace state id value))

;; INPUT: STATE and LIST-OF-IDS (VARIABLES)
;; OUTPUT: A new state that results from deleting all ids (the variables) from
;;         the specified state
(define (state-delete-all state variables)
  (cond ((null? variables) state)
        (else (state-delete-all (state-delete state (car variables)) (cdr variables)))))


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; THESE CLASSES CORRESPOND TO THE ABSTRACT SYNTAX SUCH THAT A "PROGRAM"
;; REPRESENTS A PARSE-TREE.  THESE FUNCTIONS OPERATE AT THE 'SYNTACTIC' LEVEL
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; (PROGRAM BODY)
(define (program-get-body stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

;; (BLOCK S1...SN)
(define (block-get-body stmt)
  (filter (lambda (x) (not (is-declaration? x))) (cdr stmt)))

(define (block-get-declarations stmt)
  (filter (lambda (x) (is-declaration? x)) (cdr stmt)))

;; (DECLARE TYPE VAR)
(define (declaration-get-type stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

(define (declaration-get-var stmt)
  (caddr stmt))

(define (is-declaration? stmt)
  (and (list? stmt) 
       (equal? (car stmt) 'declare)))

;; (:= VAR EXP)
(define (assignment-get-var stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

(define (assignment-get-exp stmt)
  (caddr stmt))

;; (IF TEST THEN [ELSE])
(define (if-get-test stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

(define (if-get-then stmt)
  (caddr stmt))

(define (if-has-else? stmt)
  (= (length stmt) 4))

(define (if-get-else stmt)
  (cadddr stmt))

;; (WHILE TEST BODY)
(define (while-get-test stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

(define (while-get-body stmt)
  (caddr stmt))

;; (SPRINT LABEL EXP)
(define (sprint-has-exp? stmt)
  (and (list? stmt)
       (= (length stmt) 3)))

(define (sprint-get-label? stmt)
  (cadr stmt))

(define (sprint-get-exp stmt)
  (caddr stmt))

;; INPUT: an expression EXP
;; OUTPUT: the operator of EXP (an element of ART-C)
(define (exp-get-operator exp)
  (car exp))

;; INPUT: an expression EXP
;; OUTPUT: the left-operand (an expression) of EXP
(define (exp-get-left-operand exp)
  (car (cdr exp)))

;; INPUT: an expression EXP
;; OUTPUT: the exp-get-right-operand (an expression) of EXP
(define (exp-get-right-operand exp)
  (car (cdr (cdr exp))))

;; INPUT: an expression EXP
;; OUTPUT: #t if the expression is a boolean literal and #f otherwise
(define (bool? exp)
  (or (equal? exp 'true)
      (equal? exp 'false)))

;; INPUT: a symbol
;; OUTPUT: #t if the symbol is 'true and #f if it is 'false and 'void' if neither
(define (symbol->bool sym)
  (cond ((equal? sym 'true) #t)
        ((equal? sym 'false) #f)))


;; INPUT: A PROGRAM
;; A PROGRAM has syntactic structure (program stmt)
;; OUTPUT: THE STATE that results from executing the program
;;         in an empty state.
(define (interpret-program pgm)
  (interpret (program-get-body pgm) (state-create-empty)))
```

For this assignment we've been given this library of functions as a starting point and I'm just having a few comprehension issues following all the code. Using this library of functions our task is to implement the functions within the following interpret function:

```
(define (interpret stmt state)
  (display stmt) (newline) (display state) (newline)
  (let ((kind (car stmt)))
    (cond ((equal? kind 'block) (interpret-block stmt state))
          ((equal? kind 'declare) (interpret-declaration stmt state))
          ((equal? kind ':=) (interpret-assignment stmt state))
          ((equal? kind 'if) (interpret-if stmt state))
          ((equal? kind 'sprint) (interpret-sprint stmt state))
          ((equal? kind 'while) (interpret-while stmt state))       
          (else (error (string-append "statement expected but saw (" (exp->string stmt) "...) instead."))))))
```

I'm currently working on the interpret-block function but I'm not fully seeing the purpose of this function or how to implement it. In my mind, interpret-block would only be used for calling interpert-declaration, interpret-assignment, etc, but then isn't that what interpret is doing anyways? So I guess what I'm asking is, what is interpret-block supposed to actually accomplish?

Below I've included a sample program this code is meant to interpret.

```
(define pgm '(program 
              (block
               (declare int n)
               (declare boolean error)
               (declare int result)   
               (:= error false)
               (:= result 1)
               (block 
                (declare int local)
                (:= n 5)
                (:= local n)
                (while (> local 0)
                       (block
                        (:= result (* result local))
                        (:= local (- local 1)))))
              (sprint "result: " result)
              (if (! error) (sprint "a") (sprint "b")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference:

`intepret` interprets one single expression. 
`interpret-block` takes the several statements in the one block expression and use `interpret` on each one. `interpret` will do the "right thing", like call `interpret-declaration`, based on the type of expression. `interpret-block` will have a vital role in state handling. eg. `declare` would return a new state that next statements needs to get as argument. I guess all calls to `interpret` gets a state back and in `interpret-block` would always return the passed state back to clear new bindings.

Comment: Okay, this actually helps a lot. I think I was thinking about it wrong in that interpret parses through the entire 'program (pgm)' versus interpret has a single expression at that time. So basically, interpret-block breaks apart the pieces of the block and sends them through interpret?

Comment: @nwelch Yes. It's the same as with `apply` in Scheme interpreters (which happens to be the way Scheme interpreters make new scope). Be aware that I'm guessing a little, but looking at Johns answer we both read into the state part.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading all of your code (or your assignment) in detail, I can tell you this: yes, your interpret-block function is going to call other functions: interpret-assignment, assignment-declaration, etc. The interpret-block function will need to combine the results of these functions in a way that makes sense for your language.

It looks like your language is all about state and its manipulation, so I'm guessing the result of these functions will contain information about the state
of the machine, and I can see that the state is used as an argument to these functions.

You need to reason about what the state needs to represent. I would recommend
formulating a data definition (in the [How To Design Programs](https://www.htdp.org/) sense).

Comment: If this is the case then, wouldn't you essentially be calling, for example interpret-declaration twice on the same declaration as it first be called within interpret-block, then again once we reach that declaration through interpret?